# fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

OS: Windows 10

Hello, really hope someone can help as i am desperately trying to install the QMYSQL driver. I am aware that there have been tons of posts about this, but my issue is still not resolved and i really don't know why... My mysql.h file certainly does exist, and thus its path is provided for include.  I have latest versions of Qt (5.8 with sources) and MySql (5.7). In mysql installation I chose developer default and installation was successful. I will be happy to provide any further information. I ask for anyone that can help please. Thank you.

in cmd from:

```
C:\Qt\5.8\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\mysql
```

i run:

```
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\include" "LIBS+=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\lib" mysql.pro
```

then mingw32-make as normal.

i get:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/5.8/Src/qtbase/src/plugins /sqldrivers/mysql'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=c++1z -fno-exceptions  -frtti -Wall -Wextra
 -Wvla -Wdate-time -DUNICODE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII  -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS
 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN  -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -IC:\Program -IFiles\MySQL\MySQL
 -IServer  -I5.7\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtSql\5.8.0 -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32
\include\QtSql\5.8.0\QtSql -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtCore\5.8.0 -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\
QtCore\5.8.0\QtCore -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include -IC:\Qt\5.8\mingw53_32\include\QtSql -IC:\Qt\5.8\
mingw53_32\include\QtCore -I.moc\release -IC:\utils\my_sql\my_sql\include -IC:\utils\postgresql
\pgsql\include -IC:\openssl\include -I..\..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o  .obj\release\qsql_mysql.o qsql_mysql.cpp
In file included from qsql_mysql.cpp:40:0:qsql_mysql_p.h:60:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile.Release:355: recipe for 
target '.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o'   failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [.obj/release/qsql_mysql.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 
'C:/Qt/5.8/Src/qtbase/src/plugins  /sqldrivers/mysql'
Makefile:38: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

Comment: I suspect you're being bitten by https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58372 ...

Comment: oh its a bug?! well at least I now know im not going crazy. thanks